# How do I Host an Online Minetest Server?

Tags: minetest

I want to host a minetest server on my computer, but I don't know how.

So basically, I just want to know how to, in layman's terms, how to host a server that would run off of my internet service.  That way I can decide what settings and mods are on.

Comment: Are you having an issue with something specific?  They have an official [wiki on server setup](https://wiki.minetest.net/Setting_up_a_server).

Comment: Basically I wanted layman's terms of how to create a server other people can join using my personal internet service.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to follow a tutorial, like the one in the wiki linked above or try finding a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=minetest+server+setup).  If you run into a specific problem, feel free to ask a new question, and you can always post an answer to this yourself if you think it'd be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I've found is to use Docker.

I hosted a few Minetest servers using LinuxServer.io's Docker image. All the info on how to run them is here: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/minetest

I've run them without issues for about three years even on really cheap VPS servers with less than 1GB of RAM (but for 2-3 players).

You have the option to simply run using Docker CLI, but I prefer using docker-compose, as I sometimes have more Minetest servers on the same machine.

Recently I noticed that there's an [official set of Minetest Docker images](https://github.com/minetest/minetest#docker) that you could try.